# what's the meaning of the way of writing in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
$.each(obj,function(key,value) {})
```

I am a newbie of jquery, i know there are two ways to write the structure like this:

```
$('document').ready(function(){}); or     $(function(){});
```

why `$.each()` put `.` behind `$` rather than `$(each())`

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript (and remember, jQuery is a JavaScript library that doesn't do anything you couldn't do yourself in JavaScript) functions are a type of object. Hopefully you already know how to define and call a JavaScript function, with the following syntax that is similar to many other languages:

```
function myFunction() {
   alert("This is myFunction");
}

myFunction();      // alerts "This is myFunction"
```

But because a function is also an object it can have other properties:

```
myFunction.someProperty = "test";
alert(myFunction.someProperty);    // alerts "test"
```

In that example `someProperty` was a simple string, but you can also create properties that refer to functions, i.e., that are methods:

```
myFunction.someMethod = function() {
                          alert("This is someMethod");
                        };

myFunction.someMethod();    // alerts "This is someMethod"
```

The jQuery syntax you have asked about is essentially the same thing as above, except at first it seems more complicated because the `$()` function does different things depending on the type of the parameter(s) you pass to it. But

```
$(function(){});
// is equivalent to my example
myFunction();

$.each();
// is equivalent to my example
myFunction.someMethod();
```

Some jQuery code gets a bit more confusing because in many cases jQuery function calls return a "jQuery object" that itself has a bunch of methods defined.

```
$(document)
// returns a jQuery object that has a "ready" method so you can say
$(document).ready();
// which is equivalent to 
var doc = $(document);
doc.ready();
```

Many jQuery methods return the same type of jQuery object, so you can chain calls together:

```
$('div').hide().fadeIn().fadeOut().show();
```

The last `.show()` at the end also returns a jQuery object but we aren't doing anything with it.

These concepts are all a standard part of the JavaScript language, so I suggest you work your way through a good JavaScript tutorial. If you look at the jQuery source code (i.e., the content of jQuery.js) there is a lot of confusing code to digest, but if you start by playing around with something simple like my first few examples above you'll get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

Because the jQuery object is both a function an an object. As an object it contains a lot of properties that are methods.

You can call it like this, then you use it as a function:

```
$('a')
```

You can access its properties, then you use it as an object:

```
$.each(...)
```

When you use it as a function, it returns a jQuery object, so most of the time you use it first as a function, then as an object:

```
$('a').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$.each` function is helpful for iterating through JQuery objects as well as other collections like arrays or objects. Traversing through JSON data is a good example where `$.each` is very useful.